# Is it possible to have a level of indirection in css?

Tags: css, colors

What I would like to do is have something that ties a placeholder name to a color so that I can easily substitute an entire color palette without having to change the css for individual elements.  There will be many placeholders for the same color so with a level of indirection when I want to try another palette or individual color I just have to change the master, i.e. the placeholders do not have to change when the palette changes.

```
// Pseudocode example of a level of indirection:
// this is the master color pallet
blue: dodgerblue

/* this is actual css for an element with a placeholder for color */
.openButton {
    background: blue; /* displays as dodgerblue */
 }

 // changing the palette
blue: skyblue

.openButton {
    background: blue; /* displays as skyblue */
 }
```

I should mention that currently I'm doing the following but it
 requires that the color be treated as another class which
 is not quite the indirection I'm looking for.

```
 .blue{
      color:dodgerblue;
}
```

Comment: Check out a CSS preprocessor like less or sass.

Comment: You're looking for CSS variables, which don't exist (yet). You'll need to either generate your CSS in a server-side language, where you can use variables or look into using a CSS preprocessor.

Comment: http://lesscss.org/ LESS CSS

Comment: Anyone arriving here by the time of this writing can make quick progress on this employing `postcss` and various plugins for it. Easily configurable and fast plugins are available for all manner of substitution, lookup, mapping, conversion, indirection, inlining, etc.

Answer (score 1):

that's not possible with just css (Check out for less).

I would recomend you at the start of your project, specially if very big, to have a css sheet for (as I call it) Common properties. Then one of the common properties I always add in that sheet are, among others, colors (for text and background) that are going to be used very often in the project (corporative colors).

For example:

```
.txt-color-light {color:#xxxxxx;}
.txt-color {color:#xxxxxx;}
.txt-color-dark {color:#xxxxxx;}
.bck-color-light {background-color:#xxxxxx;}
.bck-color {background-color:#xxxxxx;}
.bck-color-dark {background-color:#xxxxxx;}
```

From then I never have to add colors on any element by class (except uncommon and unique elements) I just add the class in the html when needed. At first it may be confusing by once I got use to it, it became faster, less css lines, and anytime you need to change a color in all your project you just have to change one line.

My 2 cents.-